# Android local HTTP Server, action on GET URL

Tags: java, android

I have installed this JAR inside my Android app using Android Studio

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

I have implemented it in MainActivity using this code as a basic HTTP server and I can successfully browse to the IP address on port 5000 and get the "Ok" response.

```
    AsyncHttpServer server = new AsyncHttpServer();
    java.util.List<WebSocket> _sockets = new java.util.ArrayList<WebSocket>();
    server.listen(5000);

    server.get("/screenon", new HttpServerRequestCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onRequest(AsyncHttpServerRequest request, AsyncHttpServerResponse response) {
            response.send("Ok");}
    });
```

How can I execute an action when I browse to http://ipaddress/screenon.

The code I want to execute is this (which can turn the screen on):

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

Thanks

Comment: Put in in onRequest?

Comment: Already tried this unsuccessfully, the onRequest has an unusual format, see the { at the end of the onRequest line.

Comment: There is nothing unsual to be seen. Where are you talking about? You can just put that statement in it. And lots of other code.

Comment: greenapps can you please give a code example, I'm struggling to get this to work.

Comment: I have no code. You have code you said. Just put that code in onRequest.